# Cross-class communication

Tags: c#, class, communication

I'm running a main WinForm with most UI elements, and then an Add form is called when the Add button is picked. It should receive input, and send it back to the WinForm once accepted.

This code runs when you click the "Add" button on the main class:

```
    public void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddView newadd = new AddView();
        newadd.Show();
    }
```

This code (also in the main class) should run based upon a button in the AddView:

```
    public void AddDashObject(string dashName, string dashIdentifier, int dashFunction, string dashFunctionInfo, int dashVerbosity)
    {
        DashObject tmp = new DashObject("","",0,"",0);
        tmp.DashName = dashName;
        tmp.DashIdentifier = dashIdentifier;
        tmp.DashFunction = dashFunction;
        tmp.DashFunctionInfo = dashFunctionInfo;
        tmp.DashVerbosity = dashVerbosity;
        dashloaded.Add(tmp);
        ReloadDashObjects();
    }
```

I'm not really sure how to communicate between the forms - I can use a type created in the main class, and also methods, but I'm pretty sure I'm creating a separate instance. How can I communicate with the existing one?

```
    MainView mnfrm = new MainView(); 
    MainView.DashObject tmp = new MainView.DashObject("","",0,"",1); // Defaults

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mnfrm.dashloaded.Add(tmp); // Add the default DashObject to MainView's currently loaded DashObjects
        mnfrm.ReloadDashObjects(); // Reload the list
    }
```

Not sure how to proceed on this - any advice?

Comment: Is the Add form supposed to be modal, so the main form is "locked" while user inputs in the Add form, or shall they work in parallell?

Comment: Send a reference from MainForm to AddForm, and use reference of MainForm there.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund - just noticed my accidental use of a non-modal function. It should be modal (and uses ShowDialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Add dialog is expected to be modal, the decoupled way to do this is to only close the dialog with an OK status. I.e. the form is just an input control that doesn't actually "do" anything.

Then the main form can:

1) check how the dialog was closed right after ShowDialog(),

2) call some GetResult() function to get the values from the add form before disposing it.

3) call the business logic that actually creates and reloads the DashObjects.